# How could Amagiri have eggs on him after he teleported with Brita?

Tags: darker-than-black

In episode 24 we see Brita and Amagiri teleport inside PANDORA and steal some clothes from a group of guards.

we know that Amagiri's remuneration/obeisance is to eat boiled eggs. We also know that Brita's ability is:

> Teleportation: Her ability is to teleport herself and anyone she is in
>   contact with; however, any clothing, tools, or weapons are left
>   behind.

[*Source: Darker Than Black Wikia*](http://darkerthanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Brita)

How would it be possible for Amagiri to have eggs on them after they teleported using Brita's ability?

[image: Brita & Amagiri with boiled eggs.]

Comment: My guess is maybe because clothing, tools and weapons would be "more processed" in how they are made than boiled eggs (eg. Weapons = Natural Ore that needs to be refined to produce metal and metal needs to be worked into shape VS Boiled Eggs = Eggs laid from a chicken cooked in hot water which can also be produced naturally) Brita's Power ignores anything humanity has tampered with. kinda fits with the theme that humanity is being replaced by Dolls

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the eggs he and Amber made together earlier in the episode.  He pulled it out of his pocket after she rewound time to save his life.

So Amber put the egg in his pocket.  That's why he stopped and stared at it.